# How can I tell whether a controller action was requested by DNS or IP?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

On my WebDev server, I'm trying to test whether a controller's action was requested through its raw IP, or by its DNS.  I've tried looking at the controller's `HttpRequest.Url.HostNameType`, but it seems to resolve to a DNS even if I enter my local IP in the browser.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is passed in the `Host` header of an HTTP request, so you should be able to access it like this:

```
var requestedHost = Request.Headers["Host"];
```

If the request was for an IP address, that IP address string should be returned.  Otherwise, it will be whatever hostname they used.

Answer (score 0):

[`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.authority.aspx)

Gets the Domain Name System (DNS) host name or IP address and the port number for a server.

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com:8080/");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri,"shownew.htm?date=today");

Console.WriteLine(myUri.Authority);
```

Output: www.contoso.com:8080